# Limit video duration in jwplayer rss playlist

Tags: jwplayer6

Need to set duration of the video in the following script

```
<div id='playervlKvWXHH'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playervlKvWXHH').
    setup({
        playlist: 'http://jwpsrv.com/feed/feed.rss',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        skin: 'vapor'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why ??? could you explain little bit more

Comment: Please elaborate what are you trying to do ?